# Create a new user inside the couchbase-sync-gateway's sync-function?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am about to use the couchbase-sync-gateway.
I would like it to be the only backend, so this is my question:

Is it possible to implement the user registration logic inside the Sync Gateway?

- check whether username exists
- if yes return an error message
- if no return a success message

Answer (score 0):

With `couchbase-sync-gateway` you can preform a `GET` to `http://localhost:4985/sync_gateway/_user/{username}` and will get a 200 if the username exists or 404 if their is no username.